# Hide/Disable SRP warning message

Tags: windows-10, applocker

I am using Software Restriction Policies on my Windows 10.
When I try to run any *.exe file from non-allowed places, there is the warning message:

> "This app has been blocked by your system administrator. Contact your
> system administrator for more info."

It is fine, that this application has been blocked, but I don't want this message to be displayed. I cannot find anywhere how to disable this message.
When I used SRP on Windows 7, there was no message, only log in the EventLog.
Is there a way (registry tweak or some other) to disable this message?

I can suppose, that this message was send by AppLocker, but its not active on my PC.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Your not going to be able to block the application and have nothing happen, Windows can’t be configured like that.

Comment: Note that Windows 11 version 22H2 was supposed to definitely replace Software Restriction Policies by App-Locker ([link](https://borncity.com/win/2022/11/08/windows-11-22h2-no-longer-supports-software-restriction-policies-srp/)). But for some miracle they still exist in my Windows 11 23H2.

Comment: @Ramhound I want the silent behavior like Win7 - when app was blocked, system created an event and that's all. Currently, in Widows 10 there is the same, but after system write an event about blocked app, it shows LARGE window with strange text, which does not help a user! I wish to show my message or don't show anything at all, if this file was not important for user (like dangerous file from Temp folder).

Comment: @harrymc thank you. I know it, but I don't like AppLocker and it is not suitable for my tasks. I need SRP. (btw, soon MS will replace AppLocker with WDAC.)